# Is this sentence correct? "I shall buy the book whether you like it or not."

Tags: grammaticality, learning, shall-will

> I will buy the book whether you like it or not.

Above sentence seems correct, I want to know if replacing **will** with **shall** creates any problems?

Comment: No problem, but *will* is normal speech, whereas *shall* calls special attention, like a formality or a forcefulness.

Comment: _Shall_ is no longer used in declarative sentences in American English, and in questions is limited to first person.

Comment: And in a sentence like that even *will* seems stilted:  “I’m gonna buy the book whether you like it or not.”